# User defined messages

Tags: c++, mfc, sendmessage

Here is the code:

```
//h file
class MyClass: public CView
{
public:
    afx_msg LRESULT OnMyMess(WPARAM, LPARAM);
}

//cpp file
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(MyClass, CView)
    ON_MESSAGE(WM_USER+100, OnMyMess)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

LRESULT OnMyMess(WPARAM, LPARAM)
{return 0};


//Somewhere in the programm
SendMessage(WM_USER+100, 0 ,0);
```

Why doesn't the program call the handler?

upd: WinXP, MS VS 2003

Comment: Since the answers appear to have solved your problem, please accept one.

Comment: Please use WM_APP instead of WM_USER - some of the Windows controls use messages in the range of WM_USER, which is unfortunate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First,

```
LRESULT OnMyMess(WPARAM, LPARAM)
{return 0;}
```

should be

```
LRESULT MyClass::OnMyMess(WPARAM, LPARAM)
{return 0;}
```

but I guess it's just a typo.

Second, `SendMessage` should work as expected, only if it's in the MyClass that you're calling it; otherwise, you should specify the window to which you want to send the message.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, you're right. I called SendMessage of wrong window.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are calling SendMessage() from a method not of MyClass, but of MyMainFrame, for example, so you are sending the message to the wrong window.
If that is the case, simply add the member variable:

```
m_myView.SendMessage(WM_USER+100,0,0);
```

Also you did forget the **MyClass::** from:

```
LRESULT MyClass::OnMyMess(WPARAM, LPARAM)
{return 0};
```

Comment: It seems you are right, thank you! But what's the point it? Isn't there a way to just type SendMessage(....) in any place of a program and call all handlers? Why do i need SendMessage if i just can call class methods directly having pointers or variables?

Comment: There are *member* SendMessage functions, and there is also a global win32 API that takes a HWND param. Use [::SendMessage(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for that.

Comment: Window messages are not like events in other languages. They are sent to a window (or to a thread). So when you handle a message you do it in a window. If you need a global SendMessage() you may try GetMainWnd()->SendMessage(...) anywhere in the program.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
//h file
#define CUSTOM_MESSAGE WM_USER + 100

class MyClass: public CView
{
public:
    afx_msg LRESULT OnMyMess(WPARAM, LPARAM);
}

//cpp file
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(MyClass, CView)
    ON_MESSAGE(CUSTOM_MESSAGE, OnMyMess)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

LRESULT OnMyMess(WPARAM, LPARAM)
{return 0};


//Somewhere in the programm
SendMessage(CUSTOM_MESSAGE, 0 ,0);
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but this doesn't work. I get the same result, no handler is called.

Comment: I'm not sure how this would make a change, though

Comment: This would not fix the problem, but using a #define or const declaration for the user defined message *is* a good idea.

Comment: To avoid any possible conflict, `WM_APP` should be used over `WM_USER`